# What is the term for subscribing to variable changes?

Tags: akka

I need to use actor that holds value and notifies subscribers on its update. I'm curious is it a well known pattern and if so how does it called? I'd like to read about best practices and known pitfalls in it.

Comment: pub-sub pattern? observer?